# How to send a HTTP POST like this in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, http, swift2

```
{
  "appId":"YOUR_APP_ID",
  "appKey":"YOU_APP_KEY",
  "queries":{
    "item_name":"Kids Fries",
    "brand_name":"McDonalds"
  }
}
```

I know how to handle the first two items(appId,appKey) in postString, but I don't know what the format be for "queries", I tried the following, it did not work:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url! )
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let postString = "appId=myId9&appKey=myKey&queries={item_name=burger&brand_name=McDonalds}"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: Is the server expecting all those parameters in the url? It seems like you should sent the json object in the request body.\

Comment: @piyuj yes https://developer.nutritionix.com/docs/v1_1

Comment: I think the issue is that you should sent the JSON string in the same format than your first code tag. And Specify the request content type:

`request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What Content-Type does the server expect?

You are showing `application/json` in the first part, but `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the second part.

---

If you need `application/json`, then

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
let postString = "{\"appId\":\"myId\", \"appKey\":\"myKey\", \"queries\":{\"item_name\":\"Kids Fries\", \"brand_name\":\"McDonalds\"}}"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

---

If you really need `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, then some guessing is involved. Why not try using the dot-syntax.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
let postString = "appId=myId&appKey=myKey&queries.item_name=burger&queries.brand_name=McDonalds"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Alamofire. Its really easy to do this in that.
All you have to do is do something like the following and it post;

```
    let myParams = [
        "key1":  value1 ,
        "key2":  value2,
        "key3":  value3,
        "Key4":  value4
    ]


    Alamofire.request(.POST, posturl, parameters: myParams, encoding: .JSON)
        .authenticate(user: self.postUser, password: self.postPass)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseString { response in
            print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
            if response.result.value != nil{
                let rJ = response.result.value!
                print("Response: " + rJ)
            }else
            {
                print("Fail")

            }

    }
```

Hopes this helps. And Alamofire makes get request easier too.

Answer (score 1):

## You can also try this code with Alamofire

```
let parameters = [“Username”:”name”]
        
        let headers = ["Content-Type":"application/json"]
        
        Alamofire.request(.POST, “your URL here”, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print("Response JSON: \(response.result.value)")
                //--------------------
                switch response.result {
                case .Success:
                    self.successGetData(response.result.value!)
                case .Failure(let error):
                    self.failedGetData()
                    print(error)
                }
            }
```